# A way to iterate .set method for Map() object?

Tags: javascript, loops, dictionary

Lets say I grab multiple elements. In this case image elements.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.images');
```

I have a Map() obj.

```
amountOfImages = new Map();
```

A goal to have a any future additions of images, to be set as a value using the `.set` method.

I am exploring options on data storages and have not noticed is there is a question concerning, or related to possibly using the `.set`.

I attempted using a `for()` loop. However I believe that is a incorrect usage going into Maps().

Comment: Can you try to show an example of what you're trying to do? I'm not finding this very clear.

Comment: You're struggling with detection of "future addition of images" or just the usage of your `Map`?

Comment: "I attempted..." – can you show us what you attempted?

Comment: What does a DOM collection of elements have to do with a key-value `Map`? What do you want to `.set()`?